# Nesting Multiple Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web-hosting

Is it possible to have separate multiple MVC projects within a single hosting environment?

For example I have one MVC 4 project uploaded to an external hosting environment located in the root folder and I would like to add a sub folder to host the second MVC 4 project. I have successfully published the second MVC4 project to the sub folder but when I try and access the second project I get a 403 Forbidden error or if I try to pass a specific URL I get a 404 The resource cannot be found error.

I have checked the FTP sub folder and it contains all the relevant folders and files, web.config, bin, etc...

For example if I try `www.mydomain.com` (1st MVC project) and any URL related to that project it works, if I try `www.mydomain.com\newmvc\` (2nd MVC project) I get 403 Error or `www.mydomain.com\newmvc\Index` or `www.mydomain.com\newmvc\Home\Index` I get 404 error.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this by adding an Area to the primary MVC project. This article `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(VS.100).aspx` was most useful.